Calculating Capacitance in a 50 MHz AC Circuit
I’m working on an RC circuit with a 50 MHz AC signal, a resistor, and a capacitor in series. I’m aiming to determine the capacitance value, which should be between 70 and 400 pF. To achieve this, I need to calculate the capacitance using the voltage values measured before and after the resistor, and I want to relate the output voltage to the capacitance. The error should be around 10 mF.
Here’s an overview of the circuit: the only component I can change is the resistor value.

Simulation
Could you please guide me on how to calculate the capacitance?
Maybe a solution is to use a voltage peak detector or other type of op-amp.
Thanks in advance!

Hello there -- we could use some background information. Is this a homework question? If so, please show the steps you've followed so far, and which ones you are stuck on. If not, what is your background -- what level of knowledge, what level of answer are you expecting, or would find satisfactory? What is the application? What instrumentation do you have to perform this measurement with? What accuracy do you need? Note that asking for products/recommendations are generally off topic here (and I see that has already attracted one close vote at this time).

Hi Tim , you are right, a lot of information is missing. Sorry, I’m new to this and working on a hobby project. My goal is to figure out how to measure capacitance in an RC circuit with minimal error, ideally within a 10 pF range. I know that the higher the value of the capacitor the less the amplitude of the signal after the resistor. However, I’m unsure how to measure this easily. Specifically, I’m looking for a straightforward method to generate an output signal that I can read with a standard analog pin and use to correlate with the capacitance of the RC circuit mentioned earlier

Well, one important change would be, does it have to be at 50MHz? That's a very particular choice, and not easy for a beginner to tackle. Doing it at 1kHz would be a lot easier, for example, or even 1MHz. If you don't know the analysis (e.g. AC steady state circuits), perhaps a question (or more research) on that would be more fruitful. You will also need a method to detect capacitance (frequency shift, phasing, mixer..). There are C-measuring ICs but they may not be fixed frequency; there are also VNAs, but that may more complicated than you are expecting.

This is an RC circuit and you have an AC sinusoidal source with amplitude of 1V and frequency of 50MHz. The DC offset value is not important in our calculation.
First, we calculate the Resistor voltage. For example, if we have a 70pF capacitor we get about 96mV, so:
$$|V_{in}| = \sqrt{V_R^2 + V_C^2}$$
$$|V_{R}| = \sqrt{V_{in}^2 - V_{R}^2} = \sqrt{1^2-0.096^2} \approx 0.99538$$
Now we can calculate the Resistor current:
$$I_{R} = \frac{V_{R}}{R} = \frac{0.99538}{470} \approx 2.11783mA$$
With current and voltage we can calculate the total impedance:
$$Z = \frac{V}{I} = \frac{1}{2.11783mA} \approx 472.18\Omega$$
Now we can calculate the Xc:
$$Z = \sqrt{Xc^2+R^2}$$
$$|Xc| = \sqrt{Z^2-R^2} = \sqrt{472.18^2-470^2} \approx 45.32\Omega$$
By using the capacitor reactance formula we can calculate the capacitance:
$$Xc = \frac{1}{2 \pi f C}$$
$$C = \frac{1}{2 \pi f Xc} = \frac{1}{2\pi\times 50 \times 10^6 \times 45.32} \approx 70pF $$
As we can see the calculated capacitor is equal to the assumed capacitor.
Now let's talk about the real world and measuring the capacitor with a real device. The frequency is too high so it limits us to find a good way. One approach is to find a high-speed Opamp and design a peak detector circuit then measure the voltage with a microcontroller and use those formulas to find the capacitor value and reset the peak detector circuit for the next run.

Thanks Masoud, that's very well explained. So, will this circuit work in principle? https://tinyurl.com/294hqqoq. I have added a peak detector with a switch to reset it.

You are welcome. I believe this design can do the work although you need to modify it (use a more practical circuit like High-speed opamp). Also, you should be careful about the input offset. Let me know about the results.
